# AWS Cloud Front configuration file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I've written an AWS application that I am deploying to Cloud Front using CDK. There's a config file in the src file of my application and I would like to edit this once the application is deployed, but it gets compiled into a Webpack with all the other source files so I can't.

What are the options for providing configuration in Cloud Front. I have looked at AWS Config, but this involves a charge. I can't believe this is only way to configure my application!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the source code you use for CDK, though I am confused about a few things. Are you trying to configure CloudFront or your Application that is being deployed (presumably to S3)?

Comment: It's just a simple config file I need, to store things like user pool ID, application client ID, S3 buckets, DynamoDB tables. The stuff you'd tranditionally put in an app.config file and can amend if you need without redeploying the whole application. Not sure how helpful posting code would be.